# WSGIとApacheの学習の手順に関して

Tags: python, apache, django

現在、Python3.7、Django、Apache,Ubuntu(VirtualBox)を使用して、
Webアプリケーションを作成しようと勉強しています。

インストールまではGoogleに聞きながらそれぞれなんとか入れることができました。
ですが、さっそく作り始めようと設定などをしよとしたところ、
WSGIとApacheの設定など、環境設定が全くわからず止まってしまいました。

Googleに聞きながら試行錯誤しているのですが、
まず、ApacheやPython、WSGIがどういったものなのか、どういった仕組みなのかが全くわからずやるのは無理があると気づきました。
しかし、一体どこから手をつければいいのか、自分が何がわかっていないのか全くわからない状況です。

そこで、理解しやすい学習の手順について教えていただきたいです。
また、ApacheやWSGIについて押さえておけば理解がしやすいことなど教えていただきたいです。

抽象的な質問で申し訳ありません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まずはそれぞれの役割を正しく理解することでは？極端な話、httpリクエストに対してdjangoで直接受けて直接実行することも可能ですよね？なにを学習し、身に着けたいかによって「どこから」手を付けるかはまったく変わってくると思いますが。。。インフラ要員になりたいのでなければ、以下の進め方でいかがでしょうか？

1. まずはpythonで簡単な処理をかけるようになる。(pythonの習得)
2. Webアプリケーションを作れるようになる。(djangoの習得)
3. Webアプリケーションを作って安全に公開できるようになる。(Apacheをフロントに用いた場合の設定を理解する。)

1と2は同時に実施することは可能ですが、例えば、JavaでJSP等のWeb三層を作った経験があるなどの事情がない限り、諸学者にはお勧めできません。どの機能をだれが担当しているのか全くわからなくなるので。。。

以上参考になれば。。

Comment: 役割を理解するというのは、以下のような図を自分で描けるかということです。これを描けないでやろうとすると、一つ一つの作業の意味がまったくわからなくなるので。。。https://pythonhosted.org/MyTARDIS/architecture.html

Comment: 3. の部分に関して、WSGIやApacheなどの設定ファイルの書き方などは、Google等を調べながら学習するしかないでしょうか？

Comment: やみくもにググるより、一次文書をきちんと見るのが良策だと思います。
この場合はApacheのドキュメントかDjangoのドキュメントです。おそらくfurikaeribusuさんのやりたいことはWeb APを作ることでしょうから、Djanboのドキュメントから攻めるのが、結局のところ近道です。これを読んで、そのほかの記事を参照することをお勧めします。https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/